# MKMapView Bounds

Tags: swift, apple-maps

I am going from Google Maps to Apple Maps. Google Maps has the ability to update the camera based on north east and south west coordinates like so:

```
let bounds = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(GMSCoordinateBounds(northEastSouthWestBounds), with: .zero)
self.mapView.moveCamera(bounds)
```

I know I can use `setVisibleMapRect(_:animated:)` and it takes in a `MKMapRect`. My real question is how can I create an `MKMapRect` based on north east coordinates (a CLLocation) and south west coordinates (a CLLocation).

Comment: Take a look at this piece of [MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapcamera?language=objc) documentation. Looks like `heading` is the property you are wanting to modify.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I believe `heading` refers to something else. Degree offset of the map facing true north

Comment: You're right. Misread your question. @fhipllipe answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct an [`MKMapRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmaprect) from your coordinates and pass that to either [`setVisibleMapRect(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452658-setvisiblemaprect) or [`setVisibleMapRect(_:edgePadding:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452461-setvisiblemaprect).

To create an `MKMapRect` from an array of different point types:

```swift
import MapKit

extension Array where Element == CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    func mapRect() -> MKMapRect? {
        return map(MKMapPoint.init).mapRect()
    }
}

extension Array where Element == CLLocation {
    func mapRect() -> MKMapRect? {
        return map { MKMapPoint($0.coordinate) }.mapRect()
    }
}

extension Array where Element == MKMapPoint {
    func mapRect() -> MKMapRect? {
        guard count > 0 else { return nil }

        let xs = map { $0.x }
        let ys = map { $0.y }

        let west = xs.min()!
        let east = xs.max()!
        let width = east - west

        let south = ys.min()!
        let north = ys.max()!
        let height = north - south

        return MKMapRect(x: west, y: south, width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is my real question and should update my post. How do I create an MKMapRect from bounds?

Comment: What is "bounds"? Is it an array of `MKMapPoint` or an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to return correct values that require the use of `MKMapPoint`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for.